# React-Native Edit Text in the Array

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a listing app and I want to edit this listed text. I dont know how to do this.

editTodo(key)

```
{this.state.todoList.splice(key,1);
this.setState({todoText: this.state.todoText})
```

and other thing is

```
let tds = this.state.todoList.map((val,key) => {
              return <ToDo key = {key}
                           keyval = {key} 
                           val = {val} 
                           deleteTodo = { () => this.deleteTodo(key)} /> 
});
```

but It does not work. I'm new at React-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an item from a list, you can use this code:

```
 let t = this.state.todoList;
 t.splice(key, 1);
 this.setState({todoList: t})
```

If you don't know index of item to remove, you can use this:

```
 let t = this.state.todoList;
 let i = t.indexOf(val, 0);
 if (i > -1){ //if val exist in list
    t.splice(i, 1);
 }
 this.setState({todoList: t})
```

I hope this can help you.

**EDIT:**
To edit a cell of an array, you can use this:

```
 let t = this.state.todoList;
 t[key] = 'new value'
 this.setState({todoList: t})
```

if `todoList` is an array of objects, for example:

```
let todoList: [ {id:1, name:'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}, {id:3, name:'c'}]
```

You can use this:

```
 let t = this.state.todoList;
 t[key].name = 'new name'
 t[key].id = newID
 this.setState({todoList: t})
```

or you can pass an object and assign it to cell like this:

```
Edit = (newObj) => {
    let t = this.state.todoList;
    t[key] = newObj
    this.setState({todoList: t})
}
```

Comment: I want adapt this delete method to the Edit version. How can I do that ? How can I change this code to edit method?

Comment: if its not your question, please tell me more about your problem.